How to retrieve indices of dependent columns or rows in a singular matrix
In a stability analysis study of a system of first order non linear ODEs, I am facing a problem to know exactly which columns (or rows) are dependent on others in order to eliminate them and consider only the the reduced matrix?
To be more precise in my question, let's assume that the system I am trying to study is as follows
$$
\frac{dX}{dt} = S v
$$
where $X$ is the vector of variables, $S$ is a matrix (stoichiometric matrix), and $v$ is the vector of reaction rates (function of $X$). Here $S$ is singular. The idea is to reduce it to non singular matrix $S_{red}$.
It is common to use the SVD decomposition
$$
S = U \Sigma V^{T}
$$
This is what I did. I have the rank of the matrix, $U$, $\Sigma$, and $V$, but from there I don't know how to proceed

You can use thin SVD where $U$ and $V$ are $n \times r$, $\Sigma$ is $r \times r$ diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries and $r$ is the rank of $S$. Then, you can reduce the number of variables as
$$\dot{z} = \Sigma w $$
where $z := U^T x$ and $w := V^T v$.
However, this is not the only option you have to reduce the number of variables. In fact, you have infinitely many options. For example, you can also use Schur decomposition or QR decomposition to do the same trick. But, deciding which one to select ultimately depends on your problem. Maybe, you want to optimize some cost function by a particular selection.
